# Flip type when its on a path, AI CS5

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5, typesetting

I'm putting some type on a path, a circle; but when I do it, the type is upside down. How can I flip it so it reads the right way up? See image below:

[image: Type upside down on a circle]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I remember struggling with this in CS3. I think the same fix will still apply in CS5.

### So here's what to do...

---

1. First you create the type as you did in your example.
2. You should see 3 small stripes outside of your circle. ( 2 with a small square on it, and 1 without the square) These are just indicators for where the text starts and ends
   [image]
3. grab the selection tool, and drag the stripe without the dash inside of the circle.
   [image]

---

now your type should be on the inside of your circle, and facing the right direction :D

Hope this helped ;)

Comment: works perfectly

Comment: bless you for this not obvious trick :)

Answer (score 13):

In some cases it can be as simple as choosing `Type > Type on a Path > Type on a Path options...` and then ticking the **Flip** box.

[image: type on a path options]

Comment: Thanks - which version of CS is this in ?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not certain. I think it may have been implemented somewhere around CS4.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Type on a Path Options`, select *Flip* and change *Align to Path* to **Ascender**.

[image: Click "Flip" and change Align to Path to "Ascender"]