# Type on a path starts typing upside down

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm having trouble with the type on a path tool. As soon as I click on a path, it places the text upside down. It was working fine earlier today though. How do I restore the normal behaviour?

What I've tried:

- going to [*Type* → *Type on a Path* → *Type on a Path Options*](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/114423/44433), but it's disabled until you actually type. And when flipping the text after the fact it's harder to control it's placement
- [dragging the tiny text orientation handle](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/7627/44433) works, but I have lots of text and it's not effective to do that way
- googled a lot, but most answers cover intentionally flipping the text

I'm new to Illustrator so may be missing something obvious. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer: I had to rotate the actual grid I was trying to type on.**

Turns out Illustrator may rotate the grid depending on how you create it. Since you're still looking at a grid, it's hard to tell it's orientation – hence the confusion.

For example, if you apply the grid tool exactly on the top left corner of the artboard (where it says *intersect* – which is what I did) hoping to have it aligned on the artboard perfectly, Illustrator will indeed put it right in the corner, but also rotate the grid 180°.

This is what it looks like.

[image: grid placement]

Not knowing about this "feature", I just dragged the grid down, but didn't realise it's actually rotated and not just misplaced.